# Redis `CLIENT KILL TYPE pubsub` command equivalent in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I would like to know if there is a ruby equivalent to Redis `CLIENT KILL TYPE pubsub`  command or a hack how to do it.

Thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about rewriting the Redis command to ruby using the [`redis` gem](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb), you can call **any command using the `call` method** available on the initiated Redis client. All arguments must be passed in an array together with the command name, such as this:

```
# first just an example that calling commands like this works:
Redis.new.client.call(["client", "list"])
# => "addr=127.0.0.1:37967 fd=5 name= age=338 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=32768 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=client\n

# the kill command follows:
Redis.new.client.call(["client", "kill", "type", "pubsub"])
```